# Excel match/index by column pair?

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, matching

I am definitely a beginner when it comes to advanced Excel syntax. I tried searching for an answer to my question, but I may be too inexperienced to know how to look. Also possible I misspecified my title. Apologies if this has been answered previously.

Say I have the following 3 columns

```
     A            B            C
1    Alabama      Alabama      Red
2    Alaska       Wyoming      Blue 
3    Arizona      Alaska       Yellow
4    Arkansas     Florida      Green
5    California   Arkansas     Black
```

And I want to produce a list of same-row B/C pairs that have B values equal to A values:

```
     D            E
1    Alabama      Red
2    Alaska       Yellow
3    Arkansas     Black
```

How can I do this?

Thank you thank you thank!

Comment: `IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,B1)>0, B1, "")` will get you states that have  a match between A and B. `=VLOOKUP(IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,B1)>0, B1, ""), $B$1:$C$5, 2, FALSE)` will get you those matches colors. Paste those in row 1 and copy down. You will end up with blanks and some #N/A but this will get you in the ballpark.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: hurm.. you should help to put this comment as answers to remove this question from unanswered list. ( :